# Normal subgroups from generators

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, combinatorial-group-theory

I am reading Coxeters "Generators and Relations for discrete goups". There is something in the very begin where I am struggling:

A group $G$ shall be defined by a set of $s$ relations $g_k$ between its $m$ generator elements $\{S_1,\cdots,S_m\}$ and the identity element $E$

\begin{align}
 g_1(S_1,\dots,S_m) & = E \\
 g_1(S_2,\dots,S_m) & = E \\
 \cdots \tag{1}\\
 g_s(S_2,\dots,S_m) & = E \\ 
\end{align}

and the group $G'$ shall be defined by the set of generators  $\{R_1,\cdots,R_m\}$ which fulfill the same relations (1) and another $r$ relations:

\begin{align}
 g_1(R_1,\dots,R_m) & = E \\
 g_1(R_1,\dots,R_m) & = E \\
 \cdots \tag{2}\\
 g_s(R_1,\dots,R_m) & = E \\
\cdots \\ 
 g_{s+r}(R_1,\dots,R_m) & = E \\
\end{align}

Now obviously the map
$$ S_i \mapsto R_i \;\;\; (i=1,...,m)$$ defines a group homomorphism from $G\to G'$ and all group elements
$$ g_k(R_1,\dots,R_m)  \;\;\; (k=s+1,...,s+r)\tag{3}$$ correspond to the identity element $E$ in $G'$.

To me it seems that these elements form the kernel of the group homomorphism.

So I don't understand the next step in the argument in the book, it says

> "the kernel of the homomorphism is the normal subgroup
>   $$ N \simeq \{W^{-1}g_k(S_1,\dots,S_m) W\} \;\;\; (k=s+1,...,s+r) \tag{4}$$
>   where $W$ runs through all the elements of $G$. In fact, $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ that contains the elelemts (3), and it follows that 
>   $$ G'\simeq G/N."$$

I somehow can't wrap my head around that conjugation loop over all elements how does it generate the *normal* subgroup.

I expect that it must be connected with the circumstance that iff $N$ is normal then 
\begin{align} 
WN & = NW\\
W^{-1}NW & = N = WNW^{-1}
\end{align}

must hold for all $W\in G$. But I still can't see clearly how it connects to construction (4). Possibly its very simple but I am just hanging here. Would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Consider as a concrete example the free group $F(a, b)=\langle a,b\mid -\rangle$, which maps onto $\langle a,b\mid b\rangle$. Clearly $b$ is contained in the kernel. It seems to me that you are claiming that the kernel is $\langle b\rangle$? However, $aba^{-1}$ is also contained in the kernel, while we know from the theory of free groups that $aba^{-1}\not\in\langle b\rangle$. So we need all the "obvious" things and also their conjugates, and then take the smallest subgroup containing these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importantly, the kernel of a group homomorphism is always a normal subgroup, so that it's closed under conjugations: if $f(x)=e$, then $f(gxg^{-1})=f(g)\cdot e\cdot f(g)^{-1}=e$.

For group presentations, it corresponds to a natural property of *equality*: if the word $x$ is evaluated as the identity element, meaning $x=e$ in the presented group, then for every other word $g$, we must also have $gxg^{-1}=geg^{-1}=e$.

In our example with $\varphi:G\to G'$, we obviously have $g_k(S_1,\dots, S_m)\in \ker \varphi$ if $k>s$, so the *normal subgroup* $N$ generated by these elements - which is the same as the subgroup generated by all conjugations of these -, is fully included in $\ker\varphi$. 
Moreover, it turns out that $N=\ker\varphi$, and so $G'\cong G/N$.